# How to Count Number of Line of per Class and Method in Radon?

Tags: python, pip, code-complexity

I'm using python `radon` to audit my developer's coding quality. However, I would like to count number of line for each class, method, and function.

The only options available are

- `$ radon cc test.py` Cyclomatic Complexity gives me every function (F), method (M), and class (C) rating and average score.
- `$ radon raw test.py` Raw gives me LOC, LLOC, Comment, Multi.. ect.

There is no any option specifically in `radon` that gives me the total number of line per class, method, and function. Should there be any point I was missing in document about this? How can I achieve this in python `radon`? Thanks.